# If investors are risk-neutral, should the (equity) risk premium be zero?

Tags: equities, risk, expected-return, risk-premium, risk-neutral

I looked up ChatGPT and they stated that the (equity) risk premium should be zero for a risk-neutral world. The definition of a risk-neutral investor is that one is indifferent between additional or less risk, but instead focuses only on the expected return when considering investments. Therefore, since the investor only cares about that aspect, should there be no (equity) risk premium?

Comment: yes, that is basically the original definition of a risk neutral world: a hypothetical world in which there is no equity risk premium. Let's not go around in circles...

Comment: Sure, but the investor only cares about making money. If the risk-neutral value of the call is \$4, but the lowest ask is \$5, I’m going to place a limit ask order for \$4.95. During times of high volatility, the risk premium is “negative” (traders that are long options profit, whilst traders that are selling options aren’t getting a risk-premium). 
In other words, $\mathbb{P} \neq \mathbb{Q}$.